# Facebook Insights clarification about end_date, period and API call result

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't figure out the meaning of `end_date` and `period` parameters (?) along with the result of an API call for `page_impressions` metric (without parameters).

I query for, say, `page_impressions` for the last week. Response contains the period "week" (that is the second array) and contains also 3 nested arrays with different `end_time`. This end time confuses me a lot.

**How this should be interpreted? Am i supposed to control those parameters using api() method of PHP SDK?**

This is a sample response:

```
array
  'id' => string '194501267300320/insights/page_impressions/day' (length=45)
  'name' => string 'page_impressions' (length=16)
  'period' => string 'day' (length=3)
  'values' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'value' => int 1473
          'end_time' => string '2012-01-17T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
      1 => 
        array
          'value' => int 1100
          'end_time' => string '2012-01-18T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
      2 => 
        array
          'value' => int 1194
          'end_time' => string '2012-01-19T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  'title' => string 'Daily Total Impressions' (length=23)
  'description' => string 'Daily The number of impressions seen of any content
     associated with your Page. (Total Count)' (length=92)

array
  'id' => string '194501267300320/insights/page_impressions/week' (length=46)
  'name' => string 'page_impressions' (length=16)
  'period' => string 'week' (length=4)
  'values' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'value' => int 12762
          'end_time' => string '2012-01-17T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
      1 => 
        array
          'value' => int 11943
          'end_time' => string '2012-01-18T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
      2 => 
        array
          'value' => int 12280
          'end_time' => string '2012-01-19T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
  'title' => string 'Weekly Total Impressions' (length=24)
  'description' => string 'Weekly The number of impressions seen of any content
     associated with your Page. (Total Count)' (length=93)
```

Facebook developers page says this about **`period`**:

> The length of the period during which the metrics were collected,
>   expressed in seconds as one of 86400 (day), 604800 (week), 2592000
>   (month) or 0 (lifetime) or using the function period() which takes one
>   of the strings day, week, month or lifetime.
>
> Note: Each metric may not have all periods available.

and **`end_time`**:

> The end of the period during which the metrics were collected,
>   expressed as a unix time (which should always be midnight, Pacific
>   Daylight Time) or using the function end_time_date() which takes a
>   date string in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my educated guess:

For index 0: from 2012-01-11 to 2012-01-17 there were 12762 page impressions

```
'period' => string 'week' (length=4)
 0 => 
    array
      'value' => int 12762
      'end_time' => string '2012-01-17T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
```

For index 1: from 2012-01-10 to 2012-01-16 there were 11943 page impressions

```
'period' => string 'week' (length=4)
 1 => 
    array
      'value' => int 11943
      'end_time' => string '2012-01-18T08:00:00+0000' (length=24)
```

Comment: Well that's a good starting point by the way. I've to find a way to confirm this, even if i can't understand how to pass `end_date` to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Comment: Your questions was how to interpret (you even bolded that part so we wouldn't miss it).  Not how to pass end_date.  That is a separate question altogether.  Followup questions are frowned upon unless they are created as a new question.